# Getting the next lower value with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A          B                 C                 D
1    15.000     Product 1          7.500           Product 2
2     5.000     Product 2
3     1.000     Product 3
4         0     Product 4
5
```

In **Cell C1** I type a random number *(in this case 7.500)*. Now I want that in **Cell D1** the corresponding Product is shown to the value in **Cell C1**.
Since 7.500 does not exist in **Column A** the next lower value should be used.
In this case 5.000 which belongs to Product 2.

I tried to go with the following formulas in **Cell D2** but instead of getting Product 2 I always get Product 4 as a result.

```
=VLOOKUP(F16,$A$1:$B$4,2,TRUE)
=VLOOKUP(F16,$A$1:$B$4,2)
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: `Column A` must be in ascending order to get the right value.

Comment: Hi Vinnie, thank you. Now it is working perfectly. Do you also know how I could find the next higher value instead of the next lower?

Comment: You need `match()` to do that.

Comment: thought about using an array formula With `index` and `match` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For unsorted data you can use below formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(LARGE($A$1:$A$4,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,">"&C1)+1),A1:A4,0))
```

See image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i will try it with addition columns, which indicates the difference between given 7.5 and col A like this: `=IF($C$1-A1<0,999999,$C$1-A1)` and then get the mininum value like `=MIN(E1:E4)`. then get the according value in column B.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not guaranteed to be ascending then you can use an array formula (use ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter to create an array formula)

```
=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH((C2-MIN(IF((C2-A2:A5)<0,MAX(A2:A5),C2-A2:A5))),A2:A5,0))
```

Comment: Hi Jorvik77, thank you. It works perfectly. I wonder how I have to change the formula if I want to go to the nex lower value instead of the next higher. I tried switching the MAX and the MIN but it did not work.

Comment: In this case the formula would be =INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH((MIN(IF((A2:A5-C2)<0,MAX(A2:A5),A2:A5-C2))+C2),A2:A5,0))